# Determining if on a Category Blog page or Article page

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, category

I have a shop setup using J2Store, which sets up products as articles. On the main layout I use the Category Blog layout.

I have customised the addtocart.php file to add a View Product Information button. This button takes the user to the article page.

The issue is that on the article page the same addtocart.php file is used. So I would like a way to only show the button if I am on the category blog layout. Is there a way I can determine what page/layout I am on wether to show the button or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to want to use JInput for this.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$option = $jinput->getCmd('option'); // This gets the component
$view   = $jinput->getCmd('view');   // This gets the view
$layout = $jinput->getCmd('layout'); // This gets the view's layout

if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'category' && $layout == 'blog')
{
    // Show your button here
}
```

Comment: Spot on, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This however does not work for the view and layout if there pagination is used. If you go to a next page (e.g. page 2), the $view = $jinput->getCmd('view') return nothing. Is this a bug in Joomla or is there another way to get these variables?